# How to call a rest service in listitemreader then write those list items into a flat file

Tags: spring-batch

How to call a rest service in listitemreader then write those list items into a flat file using spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

You batch job steps needs to have the following itemReader, itemProcesor and itemWriter.

1. listitemreader - read the element of the list
2. itemProcessor  - create an item processor that processes the item read - by making a test call
3. FlatFileItemWriter - writes the processor record to the file
   The Spring batch guide explains the user of reader,writer and processor in good detail - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html